# Sitefinity MVC changes to blog list view not appearing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitefinity-10

I'm attempting to add a blog to an existing Sitefinity website. I have the articles migrated in and they all seem to work with the default Bootstrap functionality.

I need to customize a few things in the MVC views. I've updated the blog list view file at `\ResourcePackages\Bootstrap\MVC\Views\Blog\List.BlogList.cshtml` (just added some random text) but there are no changes visible on the blog list page for my test blog.

I have tried rebuilding the site, no change.

I'm not terribly familiar with the paradigm used in Sitefinity, how do I go about figuring out why my changes aren't showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the you want to change the list of blog posts you have to change \ResourcePackages\Bootstrap\MVC\Views\BlogPosts\List.BlogPostList.cshtml. I would recommend you to copy and paste the template and create your own version of it, so you can have the have the default implementation intact. [Here](https://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/peter-filipov/posts/peter-filipov-blog/2016/09/27/getting-started-with-the-sitefinity-s-mvc-capabilities-(aka-feather)) you can learn more about the naming convention in Sitefinity MVC.